# Calling specific index to add a function for that index

Tags: swift

I have a `liquidFloatingActionButton` and the way you add an action is a `didSelectItemAtIndex` function. But how can I call certain indexes to add different function to each different index?

[image: Image of the error]
This is what I have so far but the error I get is:

> "cannot assign to value: 'index' is a 'let' constant".

```
func liquidFloatingActionButton(_ liquidFloatingActionButton: LiquidFloatingActionButton, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) {
    print("did Tapped! \(index)")

    if index = "0"{
        print("Buy")
    }else if index = "1"{
        print("Trade")
    }else if index = "2"{
        print("Save")
    }else if index = "3"{
        print("Message")
    }else if index = "4"{
        print("Directions")
    }

    liquidFloatingActionButton.close()
}
```

Comment: you should use `==` not `=` , otherwise you assign that value to index. Furthermore, index is not a string but a int so `if index  == 1`

Comment: i did that didnt work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cannot assign to value 'colorTouched' is a 'let' constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37399828/cannot-assign-to-value-colortouched-is-a-let-constant)

Comment: i added an image above so you can see what im talking about

Comment: you can see above maddy

Comment: @Rosalind you didn't read all of mat's comment.

Comment: the error is that you are comparing string with int. It's like comparing peer with apple. use 1 not "1"

Comment: its not a duplicate I checked. and the solution for that project did not work for mine

Comment: You actually have two problems. The duplicate only covers one of the two.

Comment: @Rosalind: As mat said: `if index == 1`, without the `"` (which means it's a String).

Comment: thanks your both right, thanks for the help. Take care guys

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 errors. The first one is that you are using an `Assignment Operator` (=) instead of a `Comparison Operators` (==).  The other error is that you are comparing string with int. 
More about basic operators [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html)

```
 func liquidFloatingActionButton(_ liquidFloatingActionButton: LiquidFloatingActionButton, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) {
        print("did Tapped! \(index)")

     if index == 0{
        print("Buy")
    }else if index == 1{
        print("Trade")
    }else if index ==  2{
        print("Save")
    }else if index == 3{
        print("Message")
    }else if index == 4{
        print("Directions")
    }

    liquidFloatingActionButton.close()
}
```